How to detect open file path within Linux module using kprobes properly?
I'm trying to hook open behavior in Linux, so i try to build a module that can log these syscalls.
I use a kprobe to hook openat2 and open, and use printk to show the params, but it turns out that I can't get the expected result (as I open the file /home/user/file.txt).
My code:
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/file.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <asm/pgtable.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>

/*
** module macros
*/
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("sena");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("hook openat");

static int sys_read_kprobe_pre_handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    char filename[256];
    struct pt_regs *user_regs;
    user_regs = task_pt_regs(current);
    if (user_regs->si) {
        if (strncpy_from_user(filename, (char __user *)user_regs->si, sizeof(filename)) > 0) {
            filename[sizeof(filename) - 1] = '\0';
            if(strstr(filename, "home/sena/testdir")){
                pr_info("openat syscall: filename: %s\n", filename);
            }    
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}


struct kprobe syscall_kprobe = {
    .symbol_name = "__x64_sys_openat",
    .pre_handler = sys_read_kprobe_pre_handler,
};

static int __init audit_init(void)
{
    int err;
    err = register_kprobe(&syscall_kprobe);
    if (err) {
        pr_err("register_kprobe() failed: %d\n", err);
        return err;
    }
    else{
        pr_info("register_kprobe() init: %d\n", err);
    }
    return 0;
}


static void __exit audit_exit(void)
{
    unregister_kprobe(&syscall_kprobe);
    pr_info("kprobe unregistered\n");
}

module_init(audit_init);
module_exit(audit_exit);


The result is:
[ 5336.037341] openat syscall: filename: /run/log/journal/3dfe2f456e1c418781ce6b6d5361db7d/system.journal
[ 5336.037362] openat syscall: filename: /run/log/journal/3dfe2f456e1c418781ce6b6d5361db7d/system.journal
[ 5336.037383] openat syscall: filename: /run/log/journal/3dfe2f456e1c418781ce6b6d5361db7d/system.journal
[ 5336.037403] openat syscall: filename: /run/log/journal/3dfe2f456e1c418781ce6b6d5361db7d/system.journal

but when I grep "home", nothing matches, even if O indeed open a file in /home/user/.
I've also tried to use the following symbol_name: __x64_sys_open, __x64_sys_openat, __x64_sys_openat2, do_sys_open, and there is no kernel log.
Also I've tried to hook sys_call_table, but sys_call_table seems no longer used when doing syscalls but used for tracing.
My kernel version: 6.5.0-41-generic.
My system: Ubuntu 22.04.4.
My test_case
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    fd = open("./file", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); //do have file in the directory
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}



You have the test completely wrong! Look at this line if(strstr("home", "filename")). It should be if(strstr(filename, "home")). Works fine for me if I do open() in my program and I hook __x64_sys_openat (of course remember that in this case you have to get the user pt_regs from regs->di first, then look at ->si.

Sorry for my mistake in writing in strstr test, i've already corrected this mistake and removed unnecessary code. actually i first did this without filtering any of the openat syscall and use grep to find the expected result. now it works! Thank you so much!!
